# How to paint a mesh using materials instead of textures

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I've sculpted a landscape, and I`d like to paint on a few different materials. Texture paint *is* fine for this, but I would like to use the settings I have created in the node set up for my materials because they have normal, bump & gloss maps attatched. Is it possible to paint using materials instead of only textures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to use masks.
Create an image to use as a mask between your shaders, and paint on that image.

Better if you can see for your self.. here is a [simple file ready to
 paint](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxfJ7ZIHabcZNXFfdTdiaGd0TGM) drive.google.com/open?id=0BxfJ7ZIHabcZNXFfdTdiaGd0TGM

If you cannot download the file, this is a very basic idea of the node setup:
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more or post some pictures? I'm really not sure I understand what the masks would do for me.

Comment: Better if you can see for your self.. here is a simple file ready to paint. It has a dirt shader and a grass shader mixed by a texture. Painting on this texture will let you choose which shader to show.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxfJ7ZIHabcZNXFfdTdiaGd0TGM

Comment: Right, when I paint it just paints the grass texture, which is accurate to what I want, but it seems to be just painting the texture, not the shader. Am I missing something or is that correct?

Comment: I didn't took the effort to make some really good materials (that was not your question). The purpose of the file is just to show the method to mix different shaders using paint.

Comment: Ahh, I checked out your node setup and I have seen the light! Would it be possible to stack this mask set up using a second mask as the factor & second mix node in order to have a third texture?

Comment: Yea I'm sorry for that, I just misunderstood how your file was set up - it seemed as though it was only painting the diffuse which wouldn't have been very helpful, I understand now.

Comment: Yes, of course! You can add more masks, or even use each channel (RGB) to have 3 masks in the same texture (4 if you use the alpha). Just keep adding. ;)